# Joining Windows domain or workgroup depending on user account?

Tags: windows, windows-8, vpn, domain, workgroup

I know that a single Windows (I'm using 8.1) computer can either be in a Domain or in a workgroup, but not both.

My home computer with my peronal user account is not in a domain, but in a workgroup (my home network). I can connect via VPN to my work network, which is a domain. Now I want, when connected via VPN to my work network, to login to my server-stored user profile in the work domain (to be able to use my work files at home).

So, I need my computer to be only in the domain when I am connected via VPN to my workplace (so that I can loging using my server-stored domain Windows user account), otherwise I need it to be in my home workgroup (so that I can use my regular local account). Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't possible. You could however use a remote session if available to access your user profile?

Comment: Or, you could alternatively find out where the share is with your files in it. If your home drive is \\SVR-STAFF\Homes$\FooBar, then VPN in and connect to it.

Comment: What resources exactly would you like to have access to if you were living into your home computer with your domain account? File shares? Printers? A home drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is not a big problem. what you can do is some thing like this :
Join your computer to the office network domain. use a vpn to connect to it then use your account in the domain to connect your data shares.

At home, keep all home computers in same network. Whatever files you and people at your home want to use, may be shared at one place in a home server or any of your computer which has one common username password. Your computer can be connected to office and home simultaneously because workgroup only bothers about same IP network range.

You may also keep two different IP address in one network Lan card. More better if you use an extra network card one for internet and one for home network.